# SQL Case Switch Default to Show Placeholder Image on Nulls

Tags: sql, null, switch-statement, case

I am trying to get a list of products and images from two tables. When I join them and use a case switch on the HasImage column from the products table, I get this error:

Error:

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= 
or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

When a product does not have an image, I want to replace it with a default image.

Here is the select statement:

```
SELECT 

P.[ProductId]
,P.[ProductName]

--If HasImage is false show the default.jpg
,Case P.[HasImage]
WHEN 'True' THEN (Select I.[FileName] as ProductImage FROM [ProductImages] I
INNER JOIN [Product] P on P.ProductId = I.ProductId
  WHERE I.Sequence=0)
WHEN 'False' THEN 'default.jpg'
END

FROM [Product] P
LEFT JOIN [ProductImages] I
on P.ProductId = I.ProductId
```

The problem is in the Case When 'True'. That's what throws the error.

Product Table

```
ProductId         ProductName       HasImage
1                 Coffee Mug        True
2                 Pen               False
3                 Pencil            False
```

Product Images Table

```
ProductId         Sequence          FileName
1                 0                 Mug_Image1.jpg
1                 1                 Mug_2.jpg
1                 2                 Mug_Img3.jpg
```

There are multiple images for ProductId=1, but I use Sequence = 0 to return only one.

The returned data I want should look like this:

```
ProductId         ProductName       ProductImage
1                 Coffee Mug        Mug_Image1.jpg
2                 Pen               default.jpg
3                 Pencil            default.jpg
```

I have tried various combinations of coalesce(NULLIF, Left Joins, and different statments, but I haven't gotten all three products to display as desired.

Comment: Could you try a LIMIT 1 (or TOP 1, depending on the dbms) clause in your inner query?

Comment: Yes that worked. and I had to add a DISTINCT at the top. That did the trick! SELECT DISTINCT
 
P.[ProductId]
,P.[ProductName]
,Case P.[HasImage]
WHEN 'True' THEN (Select TOP 1 I.[FileName] as ProductImage FROM [ProductImages] I
INNER JOIN [Product] P on P.ProductId = I.ProductId
  WHERE I.Sequence=0 )
WHEN 'False' THEN 'default.jpg'
END

FROM [Product] P
LEFT JOIN [ProductImages] I
on P.ProductId = I.ProductId

Comment: It only seems to be working. @Juniad got it right, but you added `INNER JOIN [Product] P` again and converted `WHERE P.ProductId = I.ProductId` to On clause. Your subquery brings back wrong image because it is not connected to outer query, specifically `FROM [Product] P`. You also need to remove LEFT JOIN ProductImages from outer query because you do not get anything from it, and because it duplicates records from Product. Then you can remove distinct too.

Comment: Thanks Nikola. I did not notice the extra LEFT JOIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my comment below OP, this is a query I believe should have been written in the first place.

```
SELECT 
    P.[ProductId]
   ,P.[ProductName]
   --If HasImage is false show the default.jpg
   ,Case P.[HasImage]
         WHEN 'True' 
         THEN I.[FileName]
         WHEN 'False' 
         THEN 'default.jpg'
   END
  FROM [Product] P
  LEFT JOIN [ProductImages] I
    ON P.ProductId = I.ProductId
   -- Filter Sequence 0 only
   -- All products will be retrieved
   -- whether they have associated Image with Sequence = 0
   AND I.Sequence = 0
```

Filtering right side of left join allows you to retain properties of left join AND join only rows of interest. If HasImage serves just to mark existance of Images and not as business rule (show/don't show image of this particular product), you might remove case in favor of simple `isnull(I.FileName, 'default.jpg')`.

Alternatively (Sql Server 2005 and newer) you might use [CROSS APPLY](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/10/18/sql-server-cross-apply.aspx) to retrieve images:

```
SELECT 
    P.[ProductId]
   ,P.[ProductName]
   ,I.[FileName]
  FROM [Product] P
 OUTER APPLY
 (
    SELECT CASE P.[HasImage]
           WHEN 'True' 
           THEN ProductImages.[FileName]
           WHEN 'False' 
           THEN 'default.jpg'
       END FileName
      FROM [ProductImages]
     WHERE P.ProductId = ProductImages.ProductId
       AND I.Sequence = 0
 ) I
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to go for a `INNER JOIN`?

If you are sure that when `HasImage` is TRUE your table will have an image then better go for a straight join.

Try this query -

```
SELECT P.[ProductId], 
       P.[ProductName],
       Case P.[HasImage] 
            WHEN 'True' THEN 
            (Select 
                   TOP 1 -- For Oracle 
                   I.[FileName] as ProductImage FROM [ProductImages] I
             WHERE P.ProductId = I.ProductId
             ORDER BY I.Sequence 
             LIMIT 1 -- For MySQL
             )
            WHEN 'False' THEN 'default.jpg'
         END
FROM [Product] P
```

Comment: Nope, it says Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'. I did fix the Order By I.Sequence typo too.

Comment: What are you using? Limit 1 is for MySQL. Try TOP 1.